# como puedo recorrer un array de dos en dos en javascript

Tags: javascript, array, funciones, split

tengo que poner un numero de identificación por pantalla como un promp este tiene que convertirse en un array y decir las letras del abecedario digamos si es 10 que coja la letras 10 del abecedario dejo que hice

```js
const tarjetaid = () => {
  letras = "abcdefghijklmnñopqrstvwxyz"
  let arr = letras.split("");
  console.log(arr)
  id = prompt("ingrese numero de identificacion ");
  let numeros = id.split("");
  console.log(numeros)
  for (numero of numeros) {
    document.write(arr[numero])
    document.write("<br>")
  }
  let numeros2 = (id.split("", 5));
  for (numero2 of numeros2) {
    document.write(arr[numero2])
    console.log(numero2)
  }
}

tarjetaid();
```

Comment: No entiendo el asunto, puedes ser más claro?

Comment: ¿Cual sería el problema? Tu código funciona y aparentemente bien.

Comment: Hola andres, bienvenido, parece haber una discrepancia entre el título de la pregunta y el contenido, podrías aclarar que necesitas, poniendo una entrada y la salida esperada para ella?, aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla!.

Comment: Si, que mezcla de cosas, al fin es un mumero? Un array? El abecedario? Mostrar los 10 primeros? Mostrar de 2 en 2? Si esperas respuestas claras debes hacer preguntas puntuales y claras de que es lo que quieres hacer